# How to compute (n^(n-1)^(n-2)^(n - 3)^(...)^2^1) mod m efficiently?

Tags: reference-request, number-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem (https://open.kattis.com/problems/exponial) by using fast-exponentiation but I'm getting time limit exicted.

How can I compute it efficiently?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Hint: use basic facts of modular arithmetic.

Comment: If $n \geq m$ then the answer is zero.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No, not at all. In fact, if $n$ and $m$ are coprime, the result will also be coprime to $m$. I really don’t understand why people here are treating this problem as some kind of trivial homework, as it appears rather difficult to me. Even ignoring serious complications when the modulus and base share factors, I don’t see any easier algorithm than factorize $m$ in order to compute $\varphi(m)$ (or the Liouville function $\lambda(m)$), recursively compute $e=(n-1)^{(n-2)^{\dots^1}}\pmod{\varphi(m)}$ by the same method, and finish by computing $n^e\pmod m$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek So the caret means power? First I thought it meant product, and now I think XOR. FWIW, I didn't downvote.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The OP mentions exponentiation in the question, as does the link.

Answer (score 1):

I describe an algorithm for calculating infinite modular power towers [in this Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2301050/5558) answer.

You can use it for your problem by applying it on $n, n-1, \ldots, 2, 1, 1, \ldots$.

And [as proven by Anders Kaseorg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124391/evaluate-modular-power-towers), there is a simpler method that uses the identity

$$n^k \equiv n^{\varphi(m) + (k \bmod \varphi(m))} \mod m$$

when $k \geq \varphi(m)$.